# spark sql application crashes when used with 50 gb of text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are using spark 1.6 with 6 slaves. Each slave has about 64 gb of RAM. We are converting csv files to dataframes and join them. One of the file is about 50gb and the other is is zipped to about 25 mb. Even with so much RAM, the process crashes. The big file has few million rows. Is there a rule of thumb on memory to file size. Would treating the file as a flat file instead of a CSV help?

Comment: What error do you get?  I assume outofmemoryerror, java heap space.  When you run spark-submit, what parameters do you pass in.  Just because your physical servers have 64GB memory, doesn't mean you've given the java process permission to use it all (also these are 64bit machines with 64bit java installed right, just in case).  The default memory allocation is quite small.  25MB is also small enough to make me consider a broadcast as an option to joining them.

Comment: We keep running into RPC timeout or connection stopped by peer. Update the network timeout, heartbeattimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and see if works by increasing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, default is 200, so try to increase like to 2048, play around and see if will help.

In your case best will work to convert the df into RDD and partition the  RDDs by HashPartitioner.